# Javascript canvas draw rect not working, trying to make a game board

Tags: javascript, canvas

So I made a program that is supposed to make an empty 2d game board using stroke rect or draw img. Here it is (using stroke rect):

```
window.onload = function() {

    //set up the canvas items
    var canvas = document.getElementById("paper");
    var emptySquare = canvas.getContext("2d");
    var player = canvas.getContext("2d");
    var background = canvas.getContext("2d");

    //An empty game board, with basic stats
    var boardArray = [];
    var rowNum = 7;
    var colNum = 7;

    //Makes the board with the empty squares
    for (i = 0; i < colNum; i++) {
        for (x = 0; x < rowNum; x++) {
            boardArray.push([colNum*10, rowNum*10]);
        }
    }

    //This is the png of an empty board part of an array
    var emptySquareImg = new Image();
    emptySquareImg.src = "border.png";

    function displayBoard() {
        background.fillStyle = "rgb(0, 0, 0)";
        background.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

        for (x = 0; x < boardArray.length; x++) {
            for (y = 0; y < x.length; y++) {

                emptySquare.beginPath();
                emptySquare.lineWidth = "4";
                emptySquare.strokeStyle = "rgb(200, 34, 22)";
                emptySquare.rect(boardArray[x], boardArray[y], 10, 10)
                emptySquare.stroke();

            }
        } 
    }

    displayBoard();
}
```

It does not display anything except the black background. It also throws no errors, which is sort of weird. Thank you for any help, and I can soon make my little board game!

Comment: It seems like the background is on the top layer so everything else isn't shown.

Comment: @Manu Maybe, but It is drawn first. I will get rid of that code and get back to you.

Comment: I think I figured out the problem, on your nested for loop you have y> y which whill never happen.

Comment: @Manu. Thank you so much. However. It STILL doesn't display. But, that is a good point. Now I can edit the question. =D

Comment: Try removing all the loops and try drawing the shapes without any coditions

Comment: `boardArray.push([colNum*10, rowNum*10]);`. You're creating an array of arrays, but it is not a matrix

Comment: Okay, guys I'll try these things

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few issues with your loops and generation of the array of squares. Remember to use the `var` keyword when setting up for-loops in javascript. Otherwise the variable will not be in the local scope and you probably won't get what you expect. Especially with `x` in your case since it's used in two loops.

http://jsfiddle.net/mfohao5x/

```
window.onload = function() {
    var canvas = document.getElementById("paper");
    var emptySquare = canvas.getContext("2d");
    var player = canvas.getContext("2d");
    var background = canvas.getContext("2d");

    var boardArray = [];
    var rowNum = 7;
    var colNum = 7;

    // probably worth defining the width and height of cells here
    var width = 10;
    var height = 10;

    // remember to include the keyword "var"
    for (var i = 0; i < rowNum; i++) {
      // add a new row to boardArray
      boardArray.push([]);
      for (var x = 0; x < colNum; x++) {
        // add your values for this square within this row
        boardArray[i].push([i*width, x*height]);
      }
    }
    //console.log(boardArray);

    var emptySquareImg = new Image();
    emptySquareImg.src = "border.png";

    function displayBoard() {
      background.fillStyle = "rgb(0, 0, 0)";
      background.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

      for (var x = 0; x < boardArray.length; x++) {
        // get the row here and then iterate through it
        var row = boardArray[x];

        for (var y = 0; y < row.length; y++) {
          // now row[y] will give you your square
          emptySquare.beginPath();
          emptySquare.lineWidth = "4";
          emptySquare.strokeStyle = "rgb(200, 34, 22)";
          // use row[y][0] and row[y][1] to position the rect
          emptySquare.rect(row[y][0], row[y][1], width, height);
          emptySquare.stroke();

        }
      } 
    }

    displayBoard();
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! =D That is so helpful!

Answer (score 2):

Here's your code with adjusted loops. `boardArray.push([colNum*10, rowNum*10]);` is changed to `boardArray.push([i*10, x*10]);`. `boardArray[x], boardArray[y]` is changed to `arr[0], arr[1]`.

```js
window.onload = function() {

    //set up the canvas items
    var canvas = document.getElementById("paper");
    var emptySquare = canvas.getContext("2d");
    var player = canvas.getContext("2d");
    var background = canvas.getContext("2d");

    //An empty game board, with basic stats
    var boardArray = [];
    var rowNum = 7;
    var colNum = 7;

    //Makes the board with the empty squares
    for (i = 0; i < colNum; i++) {
        for (x = 0; x < rowNum; x++) {
            boardArray.push([i*10, x*10]);
        }
    }

    //This is the png of an empty board part of an array
    var emptySquareImg = new Image();
    emptySquareImg.src = "border.png";

    function displayBoard() {
        background.fillStyle = "rgb(0, 0, 0)";
        background.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

        for (x = 0; x < colNum; x++) {
            for (y = 0; y < rowNum; y++) {

                emptySquare.beginPath();
                emptySquare.lineWidth = "4";
                emptySquare.strokeStyle = "rgb(200, 34, 22)";
                var arr = boardArray[y+x*colNum];
                emptySquare.rect(arr[0], arr[1], 10, 10)
                emptySquare.stroke();

            }
        } 
    }

    displayBoard();
}
```

```html
<canvas id='paper'></canvas>
```